# WCF Throws FaultException, client catches Exception but loses all information

Tags: c#, wcf

I am making an Async call from a client to a WCF Service.  The service is throwing a FaultException exception.  When I catch the exception in my Client "Completed" event handler, it catches the exception, but loses all information about it.  All I get is a generic type Exception with this error message: "CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound"). I have includeExceptionDetailInFaults set to true.

Why can't I catch the FaultException?

Thank you for your help.

Here is the pertinent code:

WCF Service code

```
  [WebMethod]
    [FaultContract(typeof(DivideByZeroException))]
    public int CountResults(FilterArgs args)
    {
      ...
     DivideByZeroException divByZero = new DivideByZeroException();
     throw new FaultException<DivideByZeroException>(divByZero);
```

Client code

```
    void seasClient_CountResultsCompleted(object sender, CountResultsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
          ...
        }
        catch (FaultException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("FaultException" + ex.Message);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("TimeoutException" + ex.Message);
        }
        catch (CommunicationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("CommunicationException" + ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception" + ex.Message);
        }
```

and my e.Error.ToString() message:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndGetResponse>b__9(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
   at WebAnalysis.SeasService.SeasServiceSoapClient.SeasServiceSoapClientChannel.EndCountResults(IAsyncResult result)
   at WebAnalysis.SeasService.SeasServiceSoapClient.WebAnalysis.SeasService.SeasServiceSoap.EndCountResults(IAsyncResult result)
   at WebAnalysis.SeasService.SeasServiceSoapClient.EndCountResults(IAsyncResult result)
   at WebAnalysis.SeasService.SeasServiceSoapClient.OnEndCountResults(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service code is not WCF if it is using the `[WebMethod]` attribute. It's a legacy ASMX service, which does not use `FaultException`. Look into the `SoapException` class if you can't switch to using WCF.

Comment: Thanks John.  I'm obviously a newbie and I inherited this code.